# Delete the mongo document based on date stamp

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following structure of the date and time format in json object and I would like to delete the documents created earlier than 2019 year. You can see ***created*** key with date and time stamp. We can ignore the timing. How would I delete all the document old then 2020 year.

```
db.collection.find({}).pretty()
{
"created" : "6/6/2020, 6:37:15 PM",
"created_by" : "aaaaa",
"last_updated_by" : "aaaa"
}

{
"created" : "6/6/2019, 6:37:15 PM",
"created_by" : "bbbbb",
"last_updated_by" : "bbbbb"
}

{
"created" : "6/6/2018, 6:37:15 PM",
"created_by" : "ccccc",
"last_updated" : "6/6/2018, 6:51:47 PM",
"last_updated_by" : "ccccc"
}
```

I am using the following command to delete the documents but it always return the empty.

Comment: Following command I am executing.               

db. collection.remove( { 
 created : {"$lt" : new Date(2020, 1, 1) }
 
})

Comment: This won't work because your dates are stored as string while you're passing `Date` in your query. You need to convert your data first

Answer (score 0):

If you want to programmatically work with dates, it is much easier if you store them as an ISO8601 international format, which sorts pseudo-correctly as a string, or store them as BSON date type.

In this case you can get pretty close to what you want by extracting the year from the string, converting that to int, and comparing that.

```
db.collection.remove({$expr:{$lt:[{$toInt:{$arrayElemAt:[{$split:[{$arrayElemAt:[{$split:["$created",","]},0]},"/"]},2] }},2019]}})
```